# How to make cells start with a "-"

Tags: gps

I have finally figured out how to covert dms gps to dd format the only problem is that the Longitude coordinate is not beginning with a "-" (ex 81.92754444 need to be -81.92754444). Now I have hundreds of longitude coordinates that are wrong because they are missing the "-" modifier. Is there anyway to format the cells to begin with "-"???

Comment: You've probably ignored the fields northing and easting, which most likely contians values like "E", "W", "N", "S". 
It sounds like you are using some tool, but you didn't specify. As such, I don't think that anyone can answer your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. I had no idea. I was just using "=SUM(B1)+(C1/60)+(D1/3600)". Is there anyway to use a formula to convert it? Obviously i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a smarter way to do this but whatever. 
I used =sum(-a1) to turn the number into a negative. Then I copied and pasted that number in another cell as value and deleted the previous formula. sloppy but workable